# How to create a sequential combined list in python?

Tags: python, python-itertools

I've got a list ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] and I need a list ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd'].

I've been looking at [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), but I'm not seeing how to make this work.

For [all combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python), the code would be:

```
from itertools import permutations
stuff = ['a','b','c','d']
for i in range(0, len(stuff)+1):
    for subset in permutations(stuff, i):
           print(subset)
```

What would I need to do to return only sequential combinations? I guess I could check the order for each permutation as I go, but that doesn't seem to be the best way.

Comment: Do you need `'abc'` and `'d'` there as well? Because otherwise I don't see any logic in your list.

Comment: Should `'abc'` also be in the list you want to construct?

Comment: something like `print([''.join(stuff[i:j]) for i in range(len(stuff)) for j in range(i+1, len(stuff)+1)])`

Comment: you want combinations, not permutations, or rather "ordered" combinations. See itertools.combinations

Comment: I lied, combinations are like [('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('a', 'c', 'd'), ('b', 'c', 'd')]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quite simply:

```
stuff = ['a','b','c','d']
print([''.join(stuff[i:j]) for i in range(len(stuff)) for j in range(i+1, len(stuff)+1)])
```

Gives

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd']
```

Comment: The stuff in the list will be more than one character... Will that cause a problem?

Comment: @Joseph I don't understand? the number of character in individual item does not matter.

Comment: sorry... went brain dead for a sec... saw len() and thought len(characters)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a list in-comprehension:

```
>>> [''.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])[i:j+1] for i in range(4) for j in range(i, 4)]
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd']
```

Not sure if you want to do it this way though.

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do the trick:

```
items = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
combinations = []
for i, x in enumerate(items):
    combinations.append(x)
    accum = x
    for y in items[i+1:]:
        accum += y
        combinations.append(accum)
```

Answer (score 1):

This function does it:

```
def subsequences(lst):
    return [''.join(lst[i: j+1])
            for i in range(len(lst)) 
            for j in range(i, len(lst))]

>>> subsequences(['a', 'b', 'c'])
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'b', 'bc', 'c']
>>> subsequences(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another possible solution (without using `itertools`), this time using a helper procedure for clarity:

```
def combine(lst):
    return [''.join(lst[0:i+1]) for i in xrange(len(lst))]

lst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
sum([combine(lst[i:]) for i in xrange(len(lst))], [])
=> ['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'abcd', 'b', 'bc', 'bcd', 'c', 'cd', 'd']
```