# Joke password cracker in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, character

I am trying to create a joke password cracker in python. Simply, what it will do, is create all combinations of characters from exclamation mark to space. It automatically opens notepad and in five seconds (when notepad has initialised) does pyautogui magic to simulate key presses to write lines to notepad. At the moment I have this code

```
import pyautogui, time, subprocess

pyautogui.PAUSE = 0
subprocess.Popen("notepad.exe")
time.sleep(5)

for n in range (1,3):
    for i in range (33,127):
        pyautogui.typewrite((chr(i))*n+"\n"*2)
```

but it produces:

```
!


"


...


}}


~~
```

what I need though is

```
!


"


...


~}


~~
```

can someone reply to me how to produce **every** combination of characters? Thank you!
P.S. I am working in python 3.5.

Comment: No, I am just trying to create a program which simply prints out all combinations up to a certaion value. It is just called joke_password_cracker.py

Comment: How is this supposed to work? How do you ever expect `chr(i)*n` to output two different characters?

Comment: I am not going to crack any passwords in real life. It is a crime.

Comment: I do not know how to make it work though, that is why I have asked this question.

Comment: You might look into python's `itertools.permutations` function - I believe it should give you what you need. Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find combinations, use the `itertools` module:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

>>> a = combinations_with_replacement(map(chr, range(123,127)), password_length))
>>> list(a)
[('!', '!'), ('!', '"'), ('!', '#'), ('!', '$'), ('!', '%') ........
```

Have fun waiting for it to finish when `password_length` gets around the minimum length for most passwords :)

Comment: What is this:    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\My Documents\python\pyautogui\joke_password_cracker.py", line 9, in <module>
    pyautogui.typewrite(a)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 961, in typewrite
    c = c.lower()
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'lower'

Comment: Ah, I get it, sorry for bothering you again.

Comment: Use `(''.join(i) for i in a)` to convert `a` to the format you want it in (an iterable of strings)

Answer (score -1):

## How to create simple code for password in python:

**input code**

```
password = input("Enter password:")
    
    if password == "cheese":   
        
        print("Access granted")
        
    else:
        
        print("Access denied")
```

The part `"cheese"` can be anything because it's a password.

**Output**

```
Enter password:bat

Access denied

Enter password:cheese

Access granted
```

Comment: this does not answer the OP's question; for one, the OP is asking about *output*, not *input*; please re-word your answer