# What's the best way to produce combinations in order?

Tags: python

```
l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

I want to get all the combinations in order. So the output should look like,

```
['ABCD', 'ABC', 'AB', 'A', 'BCD', 'BC', 'B', 'CD', 'C', 'D']
```

What I have tried is ..

```
>>> o = set()
>>> for i, j in enumerate(l):
    o.add(''.join(l[:i]))
    o.add(''.join(l[i:]))


>>> 
>>> o
set(['', 'ABCD', 'AB', 'D', 'BCD', 'CD', 'ABC', 'A'])
```

But it misses `BC`. Also tried `itertools.combinations` but it provides all the possible combinations irrespective of the order.

Comment: To be precise, you miss `'B', 'C'` and `'BC'`

Comment: @Antonio ?? I added.

Comment: Your question is like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17434070/2436175), but with output immediately ordered?

Comment: Standard way is recursion. You take the combinations of length 1 and place the other characters on either side. Then you take those and put characters in between those.

Comment: @Antonio I saw `(1, 3)` on their answers.

Comment: So, you want it ordered and concatenated as a string?

Comment: @Antonio ya, exactly...

Comment: @AvinashRaj I think you should reformulate the question/title to be more clear

Comment: @tobias_k I think it is meant that only consecutive combination should be generated, so not `[A,C]` because there is `B` in between

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for only consecutive subsegments of the list, just iterate the possible combinations of start and end positions and generate the accordant slices. Since the `end` position depends on the `start`, I don't think that there is a way to do this with one of `itertools` functions.

```
def comb_in_order(lst):
    for start in range(0, len(lst)):
        for end in range(len(lst), start, -1):
            yield lst[start:end]
```

Example:

```
>>> [''.join(c) for c in comb_in_order(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])]
['ABCD', 'ABC', 'AB', 'A', 'BCD', 'BC', 'B', 'CD', 'C', 'D']
```

You *could* use `itertools.product` with an additional condition, but this way you will iterate over many combinations that will be filtered out anyway, and the order of the results is slightly different:

```
>>> [''.join(lst[s:e+1]) for s,e in itertools.product(range(len(lst)), repeat=2) if s <= e]
['A', 'AB', 'ABC', 'ABCD', 'B', 'BC', 'BCD', 'C', 'CD', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to point out that every combination maps to a binary name between 0 and 2^n-1, where `n` is the length of the original string (start at 1 if you want to ignore the empty combination.  ABCD is 1111, ABC is 1110, and so on.

Generate those values and do the mapping.

Another way to look at the same thing, all the combinations for ABCD is all the combinations for BCD and all those combination with A prepended.