# How to make combinations nCr from x to y (nCx -nCy)

Tags: python, list, combinations, python-itertools

I want to make some combinations of all 160 elements in my list, but I don't want to make all possible combinations or it will never end. I just want some, lets say 1,2,3,4.

Instead of doing one by one:

```
combination = itertools.combinations(lst, 1)
combination = itertools.combinations(lst, 2)
combination = itertools.combinations(lst, 3)
combination = itertools.combinations(lst, 4)
```

How can I do all 4???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating all combinations of a list in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple `for` loop:

```
comb = []
for i in range (1,5): # (start, end + 1)
    comb[i] = itertools.combinations(lst, i)
```

Comment: I get IndexError: list assignment index out of range

Answer (score 0):

You can create single iterator containing all the combinations with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
combination = chain.from_iterable(combinations(lst, i) for i in range(1,5))
```

Example with shorter input:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(range(3), i) for i in range(1,3)))
[(0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2)]
```