# Creating all the possible combinations inside an element of list

Tags: python-3.x, list, python-itertools

I need to explore every permutations of a list. Let's say I have this initiated variable:

```
samplelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

An example output would be:

```
output = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 4, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 3, 5, 3, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]] .... and so on.
```

Here's what I did:

```
import itertools
samplelist = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

def combinations(iterable, r):

    pool = tuple(iterable)
    n = len(pool)
    if r > n:
        return
    indices = range(r)
    yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)
    while True:
        for i in reversed(range(r)):
            if indices[i] != i + n - r:
                break
        else:
            return
        indices[i] += 1
        for j in range(i+1, r):
            indices[j] = indices[j-1] + 1
        yield tuple(pool[i] for i in indices)

list(combinations_with_replacement(samplelist, 9))
```

Since the length of the list is 9, the factorial of 9 is 362,880. I'm trying to get all these combinations of the elements in the list

But my output is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: You `import itertools` but never use it, instead you appear to be copying the roughly equivalent Python code from the docs, why not use the module?

Comment: I thought I needed to import itertools since I found the function source code in here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

Comment: use the module! like `for comb in itertools.combinations(samplelist, 9): print(comb)`

Comment: Also you can use an input with less items(like 3 or 4). With that you can identify if it is working as expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating all combinations of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

itertools.permutations(samplelist) returns the 9! lists