# Python How to know if numbers in a list equal to a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sum, numbers

So let's say I have a list,

```
[23, 62, 82, 41, 12]
```

How would I check to see if a number, say 115, is the sum of *any* of those numbers and how would I get the said numbers that add up to it?

in this case the answer would be:

```
[41, 12, 62]
```

How would I do this?

Comment: "How would I check to see if a number, say 115, is the sum of *any* of those numbers and how would I get the said numbers that add up to it?" – You do it by writing a program which does that. If you have a problem with your program, carefully read the documentation of all the methods, classes, modules, and libraries you are using, write tests for your programs, trace the execution with pen and paper, single-step it in a debugger, then sleep on it, start again from the beginning, sleep on it again, and *then and only then* ask a focused, narrow question on [so] with a [mcve].

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mcve].

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Please, also provide a [mcve].

Comment: I would just like to know if there are any inbuilt functions that could help me with it.

Comment: You need to use `itertools.combinations(iterable, r)` to get all combinations of length r, loop r=1,2,3....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how.

```
import itertools
magicnumber=115
a = [23, 62, 82, 41, 12]
for L in range(0, len(a)+1):
        for subset in itertools.combinations(a, L):
        b = sum(int(i) for i in subset)              
        if b == magicnumber:        
            print(subset)
```

[... I googled "python combinations" and "python subsets" to get started ...]

[... .combinations not .permutations, sorry ...]

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly, this is what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I wrote permutations, it should be combinations.

Comment: would you mind telling me how it could print out *all* possible combinations, including the same numbers, in a different order?

Comment: Give an  example. Not sure what you mean.

Comment: So if the result was 5, 10, 16 then it would also do 10, 5, 16  ,  16, 10, 5 , and so on

Comment: replace combination with permutation