# Construct all single values, pairs, triples, etc, given a range of numbers

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I need to write a code that takes in a total number of users:

```
`N = 3` (for example)
```

from this, I need to create a list of lists, containing all single-element lists, pairs, triples (etc, but for this case, triples is max).

```
[ [1], [2], [3], [1,2], [1,3], [2,3], [1,2,3] ]
```

Code I have now:

```
from itertools import combinations

N = 3
comb_lst = []

for idx in range(1, N+1):
    comb = combinations([1, 2, 3], idx)
    for i in comb:
        comb_lst += [list(i)]

print(comb_lst)
```

The problem is I don't think this will scale to thousands of users, so is there a faster method?

Comment: No, it will not scale to thousands of users, but only because the total number of possible combinations is `(2 ** n) - 1` (assuming you want indeed combinations, where order is not important), so you probably won't be able to get past a few dozens. You can switch to a generator to at least save the space, if you can work with that, but time complexity will just be intractable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating all combinations of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach is correct and efficient. Some small improvement:

```
import itertools

N = 3
numbers = list(range(N+1))

result = []
for i in range(1, N+1):
    result.extend(itertools.combinations(numbers, i))
```

Results:

```
result
Out[2]: [(1), (2), (3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (1, 2, 3)]
```

And if you want the pairs/triples with the same element repeated use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement()`.

Answer (score 0):

Minimal complexity is number of comb_lst. Count of this is 2**N. You can include or not include each element(2 variant for one element). So for N near 1000 its not scale