# How to get every possible combination of list integers?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `L = [3, 4, 1, 5, 9]` and I want to get every possible numbers that can be made by using those numbers present in list `L`. I mean, I want to get an output like this: `[3, 4, 1, 5, 9, 34, . . . . , 91, 953, ... ,41593, ... etc.]`
I am using this code:

```
from itertools import combinations
possible_numbers = []

output = (sum([list(map(list, combinations(L, i))) for i in range(len(L) + 1)], []))
output.pop(0)

for x in output:
    strings = [str(integer) for integer in x]
    a_string = "".join(strings)
    possible_numbers.append(int(a_string))
    print(output)
```

But I am getting this type of output:

```
[3,4,1,5,9,34,31,35,39, 4145,49,15,19,59,341,345,349,315,319,359,415,419,459,159,3415,3419,3459,3159,4159,34159]
```

Clearly this is not what I want, because there can be more possible combinations formed with list `L`. Can anyone please help.

Comment: Maybe you should rewrite the line `output = (sum ....)` into several lines with normal `for` loops. This is too complicated for me to understand if it's correct or not (and apparently, for you, too).

Comment: use `permutations` instead of `combinations` (then I get 325 numbers in the list)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating all combinations of a list in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434070/generating-all-combinations-of-a-list-in-python)

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, Before posting this question, I visited that answer, but it didn't work for me as I wanted a list of numbers, not an integer combination.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```py
from itertools import permutations

L = [3, 4, 1, 5, 9]

for i in range(1, len(L) + 1):
    for p in permutations(L, i):
        print(int("".join(map(str, p))))
```

Prints:

```
3
4
1
5
9
34
31
35

...

95431
95413
95134
95143
```